# Did Jesus add to the words of Moses from Deuteronomy 6:5?

Tags: greek, hebrew, translation-philosophy, hebrew-bible, new-testament

I'm not sure if this is to do with Hebrew being translated to Greek, but when looking at "The greatest commandment" Deuteronomy 6:5 says:

> "And thou shalt love the LORD thy God with all thy heart, and with all thy soul, and with all thy might." (KJV)

Jesus seems to quote the same verse in the New Testament:

- Matthew 22:37 quoting the same verse has the words *heart, soul* and *mind* (KJV).
- Mark 12:30 quoting the same verse has the words *heart, soul, mind* and *strength* (KJV).
- Luke 10:27 quoting the same verse has the words *heart, soul, strength* and *mind* (KJV).

Why is the word "mind" quoted by Jesus in the New Testament, but not in Dueteronomy 6:5 when I read the Old Testament?  Did Jesus add to what Moses said originally?

Answer (score 1):

According to Ellicott's Commentary on Deuteronomy 6:5, the Hebrew word for *heart* clearly includes the concepts of both *thought* and *affection*. The Greek word for *heart*, however, is not necessarily so obviously includes the idea of *thought* or *mind*. To make it explicitly clear, Mark includes the word *mind* in Mark 12:30.

Ellicott's Commentary
https://biblehub.com/deuteronomy/6-5.htm

> The word "heart" has been taken both as "thought" and "affection." Hence, perhaps, the four terms, "heart, mind, soul, and strength," which we find in St. Mark 12:30.

Did Jesus add to the words of Moses from Deuteronomy 6:5?

No, not in the semantic sense. Jesus brought out the meanings that were in the original Hebrew. In any case, the idea is that we should love God with our whole being.

Answer (score 0):

Re: the QUESTION   was asked (by Michael) "Did Jesus add to the Words of Moses from DEUTERONOMY 6:5 in MATTHEW 22:37 in regards to the use of the word "might" in the OT and Jesus used the word "mind" in the NT.(KJV)
ANSWER: no he didn't. 
We know first of all from scripture that we are not to "add" or "diminish" from Gods word. Read REVELATION  22:18 & 19 says "don't add or take away".(God is not into take-aways!)Jesus simply expanded it.He quoted the the Greek translation that can mean "full" so that covers all.It covers when you think about it : intellect,might ,mind and also the word thorough.
Dennis  user 32276